# Error while creating a email function to send mails using various templates

Tags: php, class, email, templates, smtp

I am trying to create a php class to send mails using various templates. For example I want to send welcome mail with username and password. I am trying to make a email function called `sendwelcomemail()` which is accessing default php mailer configuration from class `getmailautho()`.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Include the PHPMailer class
include('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

class email {


public function getmailauth(){

    // Setup PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();

// This is the SMTP mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

// Remove these next 3 lines if you dont need SMTP authentication
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'testing';
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

// Set who the email is coming from
$mail->SetFrom('testing@gmail.com', 'test');


}

function sendwelcomemail($username,$password,$to){
    $this->getmailauth();
    global $mail;
    // Retrieve the email template required
$message = file_get_contents('templates/welcome.html');

// Replace the % with the actual information
$message = str_replace('%username%', $username, $message);
$message = str_replace('%password%', $password, $message);


// Set who the email is sending to
$mail->AddAddress($to);

// Set the subject
$mail->Subject = 'Your account information';

//Set the message
$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

// Send the email
if(!$mail->Send()) {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

}
}
?>


<h3> testing </h3>
<?php
$email = new email;
$email->sendwelcomemail("test","test","test@test.com");

?>
```

When i run this script, I am getting following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function AddAddress() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\mail_function.php on line 49

Can you guys help me out with this error? Also any suggestions welcome :)

Comment: create constructor and add initialise mail in that and then access it in other functions with $this->mail it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your mail object inside a `__constructor()` or define it outside functions (to make the PHPMailer object accessible to other functions) and remove global $mail from `sendwelcomemail()`

```
<?php
// Include the PHPMailer class
include('PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

class email {
    private $mail;
function __constructor(){
// Setup PHPMailer
$this->$mail = new PHPMailer();
}

public function getmailauth(){

$this->$mail->IsSMTP();

// This is the SMTP mail server
$this->$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

// Remove these next 3 lines if you dont need SMTP authentication
$this->$mail->Port = 587;
$this->$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$this->$mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';
$this->$mail->Password = 'testing';
$this->$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);

// Set who the email is coming from
$this->$mail->SetFrom('testing@gmail.com', 'test');


}

function sendwelcomemail($username,$password,$to){
    $this->getmailauth();
    // Retrieve the email template required
$message = file_get_contents('templates/welcome.html');

// Replace the % with the actual information
$message = str_replace('%username%', $username, $message);
$message = str_replace('%password%', $password, $message);


// Set who the email is sending to
$this->$mail->AddAddress($to);

// Set the subject
$this->$mail->Subject = 'Your account information';

//Set the message
$this->$mail->MsgHTML($message);
$this->$mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

// Send the email
if(!$this->$mail->Send()) {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $this->$mail->ErrorInfo;
}

}
}
?>


<h3> testing </h3>
<?php
$email = new email;
$email->sendwelcomemail("test","test","test@test.com");

?>
```

Comment: defining $mail above functions dint work.. Its giving error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mail' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\db\mail_function.php on line 8" . Line 8 is  "$mail = new PHPMailer();"